# The "reward an existing answer" bounty option should not say "one or more" since you cannot award the bounty to more than one answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties, wording

Right now, the "reward an existing bounty" option bears the description:

> One *or more* of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

The "or more" seems out of place, since you cannot award the bounty to "one or more" answers. Can we just remove "or more":

> One of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Comment: I think it's a subtle hint for you to post several bounties in sequence

Comment: Apparently too subtle. I would argue instead that the intent is to consider if there are more than one good answer, and then determine which is the best. The wording just acknowledges that the choice may be difficult.